# Youtube API setvolume not working on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ipad, youtube-api, tablet

I have built a chromeless youtube player in a webpage, using the iframe API from [the youtube dev site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality). Everything works like a charm, except when I view my page on an iPad or Android device, the video's volume and mute controls do not work.

```
_player.mute()
_player.setVolume(0);
```

Strangely, the other controls DO work, for example:

```
_player.pauseVideo();
_player.playVideo();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, you just need to run it after player is ready and functioning.

But on mobile devices, volume depends on the device's own setting rather than the player. So setVolume doesn't have any effect.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/iulukaya/XQ4bz/

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player; function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '250',
        width: '444',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }   }); }

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    event.target.setVolume(0); }
```

Comment: This JSFiddle does not work on the iPad either. The youtube player keeps saying "video not available" (I've tried different videos). It does work on firefox, safari and chrome on the desktop.

I've also tried copying the code to a clean html file without JSFiddle, but the effect is the same.

Comment: On mobile devices, volume depends on the device's own setting rather than the player. That should be the reason.

Comment: Thanks, that might explain it. I will just hide the volume button on mobile devices then.