# How to change the volume of a youtube video in iOS using youtube-ios-player-helper library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I use the iOS library called "youtube-ios-player-helper" to embed youtube videos in my iOS app. However, I cannot change the volume, and there seems to be no function in the library doing that. So I want to add this functionality.

I looked into the main file of the library (YTPlayerView.m) to try to know how to do that:
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Classes/YTPlayerView.m

In this file there are some call to javascript functions, that are made by google in their Youtube API. The reference given is
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setVolume
I found on this reference that there is a function to change the volume, namely

```
player.setVolume(volume:Number):Void
```

With the description: "Sets the volume. Accepts an integer between 0 and 100."

I almost don't know Objective-C at all, but using copy-paste of other functions from YTPlayerView.m (especially the function seekToSeconds), I added the following function, that is supposed to call the Youtube API javascript function.

```
- (void)setVolume:(int)volume {
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player.setVolume(%d);", volume];
    NSLog(@"%@",command); // for debugging
    [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:command];
}
```

I added also the reference to the function in the library .h file :

```
- (void)setVolume:(int)volume;
```

Then I call it from my swift code using

```
@IBOutlet weak var youtubeView: YTPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   youtubeView.setVolume(Int32(20)) 

   videoID = "QDYfEBY9NM4"
   let playerVars: [AnyHashable: Any] =
            ["playsinline" : 1,
             "origin": "https://www.youtube.com"]
   self.youtubeView.load(withVideoId: videoID, playerVars: playerVars)

   youtubeView.setVolume(Int32(20)) // called twice just in case
}

@IBAction func playButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    youtubeView.playVideo()
}
```

to try diminishing the volume of the video, which is at 100 by default. Modifying the volume of the whole phone doesn't solve my problem as I play other sounds in the app at the same time and what I want is to diminish the youtube sound relatively to the other sounds.

The code runs, the function I made is called (which I know thanks to the NSLog in it), but the sound of the video is not diminished, and even if I set the value to zero instead of 20 there is no effect whatsoever.

Do you know how to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally problem solved ! We can now change the volume of youtube programmatically on iOS :)
I put my solution on my github :
https://github.com/nicokla/volumeYoutubeIosOk

Answer (score 1):

You have to also change the volume of the phone:

Try this:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 0; // min volume (mute)
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT 1:**

I added on to your helper function to make it easier to use.

```
- (void)setVolume:(int)volume {
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player.setVolume(%d);", volume];
    NSLog(@"%@",command); // for debugging
    [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:command];

    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> // JUST MAKE SURE THIS IS IMPORTED
    musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    musicPlayer.volume = volume; // min volume (mute)
}
```

This also changes the device volume. So whenever you change the volume of a YouTube video, the device volume will also change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I also play some sound other than the youtube video in my app, so what I want is control over the youtube volume in particular, so that the rest of the sound can still be heard.

Comment: Does this work? If it does please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: No sorry it doesn't solve my problem. I need to change the volume of the youtube video, relatively to other sound playing at the same time. So changing the volume of the whole phone doesn't help. Actually I will modify my question to be more specific and explain that the mute case is just for the test, my real goal being not to mute the video but to really control its own individual volume.

Comment: It IS possible to play two sounds at once but not at two DIFFERENT volumes, they have to be at the same volume level.

Comment: Actually this is not true. I manage to change the volume of the other source of sound (I use the AudioKit library to play sound next to the video).

Comment: Ok then this seems to be a problem with the YouTube API, please file a request to get it patched.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to add a function to a library similar to youtube-ios-player-helper, 
https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView
but it didn't work either. I will try to ask the youtube iframe API people if they could do a patch or help me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using another way (adding a function to the library 
https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView
) and it still did not work.

Also I found this post with somebody having a similar problem and didn't manage to solve it :
[Youtube API setvolume not working on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386594/youtube-api-setvolume-not-working-on-ios)

So it seems the setVolume() function of the iFrame Youtube API is not working when the youtube reader is embed in an iOS WebView.